# Changing text color if text contains hashtag "#"

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

Basically I want to achieve a "hashtag" feature.
I'm having a hard time making a logic wherein if the text contains a "#" (eg. I love #flutter), the #flutter text will change its color to blue.

Can you give me a hint on what widget to use or is there a package for this?

I can't seem to find a similar problem.

Comment: I tried and it does not change its color. Can you, please, show a screenshot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `RichText` you can create a text with different styles, where each text is a `TextSpan`, like this:

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(text: "I love "),
      TextSpan(text: "#flutter", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
    ],
  ),
)
```

You could take a `String` and create a list of texts and hashtags, then map that list checking: if the element contains `#` then use a `TextSpan` with color blue, otherwise use a default `TextSpan`.

Here is a quick working example, you could try to improve it:

```
RichText _convertHashtag(String text) {
  List<String> split = text.split(RegExp("#"));
  List<String> hashtags = split.getRange(1, split.length).fold([], (t, e) {
    var texts = e.split(" ");
    if (texts.length > 1) {
      return List.from(t)
        ..addAll(["#${texts.first}", "${e.substring(texts.first.length)}"]);
    }
    return List.from(t)..add("#${texts.first}");
  });
  return RichText(
    text: TextSpan(
      children: [TextSpan(text: split.first)]..addAll(hashtags
          .map((text) => text.contains("#")
              ? TextSpan(text: text, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue))
              : TextSpan(text: text))
          .toList()),
    ),
  );
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text('#hashtag')),
    body: Center(
      child: _convertHashtag("I love #flutter and #android very much"),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro! One last thing. I can't seem to find how to `overflow` using TextSpan. It's my first time using this widget.

Comment: This is a quick solution, you could improve it to make it easier to apply any style you want. About the overflow, RichText has the property

Comment: Hey, What changes we need to make if we want it to work for text containing both @ and #. First of all, I split the text as List<String> split = text.split(RegExp("@|#")); but what changes need to be made further?

Answer (score 2):

hope this works!

```
Widget _getColoredHashtagText(String text) {
  if (text.contains('#')) {
    var preHashtag = text.substring(0, text.indexOf('#'));
    var postHashtag = text.substring(text.indexOf('#'));
    var hashTag = postHashtag;
    var other;
    if (postHashtag.contains(' ')) {
      hashTag = postHashtag.substring(0, postHashtag.indexOf(' '));
      other = postHashtag.substring(postHashtag.indexOf(' '));
    }
    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
        children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(text: preHashtag),
          TextSpan(text: hashTag, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
          TextSpan(text: other != null ? other : ""),
        ],
      ),
    );
  } else {
    return Text(text);
  }
}
```

Comment: I've got the gist of your code bro. But unfortunately it only works on the first ```#``` .

Comment: example I have  "#flutter is the #best" #flutter is the only one colored blue

Answer (score 0):

```
HashTagText
```

https://pub.dev/packages/hashtagtext#-installing-tab-

I published this library. It will auto detect hash tags from string and make highlighted.

```
dependencies:
  hashtagtext: ^0.0.1
```

[image]
EXAMPLE

```
HashTagText(text: "I will found and #highlight all #tag and #make it #clickable", onHashTagClick: (tag){
              print("You clicked on $tag");
            },)
```